# How to get the name of a Windows message inside WndProc method?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, winapi

I am overriding the WndProc method to process windows messages but when I print the message.Msg, it's an integer in the form of 49334. How can I get the actual even name or number using this value?

I have the list of messages here:
http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/misc/SendMessageList.htm

Comment: Message numbers between 0xc000 and 0xffff are registered messages, underlying winapi function is RegisterWindowMessage().  Used by code to ensure that it can communicate with a guaranteed unique message number that won't collide.  Clearly you never want to mess with them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a direct way to get the "name" - the actual message **is** the integer ID code.

You could take the list you linked and build a `Dictionary<int,string>` to map the ID to a "name" you want to report or use, however.

Comment: Thanks Reed, do you know how to convert from int to 0x00 form so I can at least do a quick look up by hand?

Comment: @JoanVenge You can enter values in 0x00 form, too - otherwise, a spreadsheet should be able to convert those in bulk

Comment: Thanks, I meant for example if I get a value like 49334, how can I convert it into 0x00 programmatically so I can do manual look up as it's only a single message I am interested in?

Comment: The Windows Calculator has a Programmer modus.

Comment: Thanks Henk, I looked at it now but I don't see the proper values that exist on the page I linked. I get C0B6? There is no even with that value, or am I converting it incorrectly?

Comment: @JoanVenge That sounds like a user specified message, not a standard message... Windows Messages can use any int, and you can send your own with the Windows API.  See here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644931(v=vs.85).aspx  0xC*** is a standard way to define a custom string message.